# ipython terminal : keyboard input perturbed after plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, qt4, ipython, macports

I'm using ipython 1.1.0 (installed with macports) and matplotlib 1.3.1 with the qt4agg backend (I'm on a mac, and can't use the 'macosx' backend for [other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020882/update-an-artiste-line2d-on-a-figure-without-re-drawing-the-whole-figure-axe)). I have a very frustrating problem :

I can't type normally in the ipython terminal. Sometimes it's ok, and most of the time I see what I type only a while after. If I click one the python 'rocket icon" I immediately see what's been typed in the terminal.

To me that looks like the terminal is being stuck by the event loop, is that right ? A while ago I had a similar issue and I was advised to start ipython with the --pylab option and that worked well at the time (other computer, other time...). I've tried that and nothing's changed, still having the issue.

I've tried starting ipython with --gui=qt4 too and still the same issue.

I don't have the problem if I just start ipython without any option. But as soon as I plot something : problem...

here is how I installed the thing  :

```
sudo port install py27-ipython+notebook+parallel+pyqt4+scientific
sudo port install py27-matplotlib +qt4
```

Comment: Get anaconda `python` (from continuum.com) distribution a shot. https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/. To have ipython working fully in OsX is always a challenge.

Comment: seriously? :-)
I just spent the afternoon installing python with macport because it didn't work with the anaconda distribution. As far as I understand anaconda only allows the macosx backend, which, as I mentioned, is causing problems.

Comment: I **may** have found a solution : https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4431
I'm running on Mavericks too... I typed the command : defaults write org.python.python NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES and the issue seems to have disappeared....

Comment: Glad that you solved it. Something to keep in mind for sure. But it is not entirely true that only `MacOSX` backend is supported. Anaconda supports other `backend`s, only the figures will not show up. But, for example, if you issue a `plt.savefig('Some_Name')`, you still get the figures.

Comment: I was talking about interactive backends :)

Answer (score 0):

So I definitely think there's a bug, either in Qt or ipython or Mac OS 10.9, but typing

```
defaults write org.python.python NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES
```

did solve my problem. Again my ipython/matplotlib etc. has been installed with macports.
That's a workaround, but for now it is alright.

sources : [here](https://support.enthought.com/entries/22861925-OS-X-10-9-Mavericks-Python-Canopy) and [there](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4431)